# how to bind specific interface in docker container?

Tags: docker

I have a program which has two mandatory arguments -d and -t, both of them mean that bind to a specific network device (IP address), i.e.: ./myprogram -d 172.17.0.2 -t 172.17.0.3, and they can't be the same.

Now, I need to run this program in a docker container, how could I config the container so that I can run this program inside the container and for peer endpoint it is the same as I run this program in the host?

Thanks!

Comment: not sure what you mean, but if your container needs to access your network device, you need to share the network devices `docker run --net-host...` extract from https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#ipc-settings---ipc `Network: host

With the network set to host a container will share the host’s network stack and all interfaces from the host will be available to the container. `

Comment: Thanks! This is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your container needs to access your network device, you need to share the network devices

`docker run --net-host...`

extract from

docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#ipc-settings---ipc

Network: host With the network set to host a container will share the host’s network stack and all interfaces from the host will be available to the container.

an example, extract from this image using nethogs for network monitoring

https://hub.docker.com/r/k3ck3c/nethogs/

`docker run -it --net=host -- --rm k3ck3c/nethogs`